# MySQL foreign key contraint allow nulls not working

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I can't seem to figure out why my foreign key constraints aren't working. Here's my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `templates_textboxes` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `template_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `textbox_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `templates_textboxes_to_templates_idx` (`template_id`),
  KEY `templates_textboxes_to_textboxes_idx` (`textbox_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `templates_textboxes_to_templates` FOREIGN KEY (`template_id`) REFERENCES `templates` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$

CREATE TABLE `textboxes` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `columns` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `width` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `height` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `x` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `y` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `z` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '500',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `textboxes_to_templates_textboxes` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `templates_textboxes` (`textbox_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

When I create a textbox in PHP, first I insert into textboxes to get the ID then insert a row in the match table templates_textboxes with the template id and new textbox id. I've read every post I can find on here about foreign keys allowing nulls and all it says to do is to set the foreign key column (templates_textboxes.textbox_id) to allow nulls. I tried that and when I try to insert into textboxes I get the following error:

```
Error Number: 1452
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pitchperfect`.`textboxes`, CONSTRAINT `textboxes_to_templates_textboxes` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `templates_textboxes` (`textbox_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION)INSERT INTO `textboxes` (`content`, `columns`, `width`, `height`, `x`, `y`, `z`) VALUES ('', '1', '400', '300', '133', '93', '500')
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is have cascade deletes chain from themes, to templates and their assets (templates_textboxes -> textboxes).
Thanks!

Comment: I would try changing `templates_textboxes.textbook_id` to `NOT NULL`. Also, try executing `SHOW INNODB STATUS` after the error.

Comment: Tried that, same error. Wouldn't that mean that a match would have to exist? That isn't possible with how they need to be inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `textboxes.id` is not yet defined and is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, that value must first exist in `templates_textboxes.textbox_id`. This is why the constraint is failing.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. templates_textboxes.textbox_id IS textboxes.id, so how can it exist first?

Comment: Because the `id` is generated by `textboxes`, there is no way that it can reference `templates_textboxes`. I think what you want is the reference coming the other way.

Comment: Isn't there a way to allow a foreign key to reference NULL? That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @Jonathan There is not; it must be `NULL` or reference an actual point.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. Thanks!